# Raspberry Pi unable to run Intel x64 binary

Tags: pi-3

despite having rasperry pi model 3 ver.2 with raspian jessie from official webpage i am unable to run a binary file; on `file foobin` i get:
ELF 64bit lsb shared object x86-64 version 1 dynamically linked, interpreter ...

upon run it says `bash: ./binary_name: cannot execute binary file` which cannot be the case, on lscpu i get architecture armv7l 1200mhz but dont know what to do; is the rpi not having x64 or the binary not being x64?

when will it be able to run x64, is it sw or hw problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pi has an ARM processor and can't run intel code (64 bit or other).

NOTE the current kernel is 32 bit.

Comment: this is repulsive marketing, the website clearly states: `Quad Core 1.2GHz Broadcom BCM2837 64bit CPU` suggesting deceptively i can run x64 code; please be open about it state it clearly where the diff is. the heck; source https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/

Comment: @ItsmeJulian the Pi does indeed have an ARM64 CPU and CAN run 64 bit ARM code. It would not suggest to anyone that it can run intel x64 code. There are 64bit OS for the Pi, but Raspbian is not - it seems pointless with 1GB RAM!

Comment: @Milliways thank you, i see: intel x64 and armx64 binaries differ, but even if i had an armx64, i cant run it since the current kernel is 32bit also the hardware would support it.